# Чому перелічний, а не переліченний?

Tags: прикметники, суфікси

Я був думав, що подібно до *зліченний* має бути *переліченний*, але [Мейнарович і Кратко не згодні](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=enumerable&highlight=on):

> **enumerable** = [ɪ'nju:mərəbl] **1.** зліче́нний; перелічни́й **2.** нумеро́вний

Я так розумію, що варіант **-енн** може мати місце коли заміна наростка на  **-н-** призводить немилозвучності, але ж тут ми маємо два однакові корені.

Матчастина від [Кочерга О., Пілецький В., 2010](https://r2u.org.ua/node/162):

> Почнімо із прикметників, що вказують на здатність бути підданим певній дії (тобто *пасивну* здатність). Такі науково-технічні терміни неодноразово аналізував Виталь Моргунюк (див., наприклад, його публікації в матеріялах попередніх конференцій *СловоСвіт*; докладний огляд його підходів див. у 1). Згадані прикметники найчастіше утворюємо від префіксових перехідних дієслів, додаючи суфікс **-н-** до дієслівного твірної основи й водночас відтинаючи від неї суфікси **-и-, -а-, -і-, -ну-** : *змін-и-ти/змін-н-ий, передбач-и-ти/ передбач-н-ий, згин-а-ти/згин-н-ий, розв’яз-а-ти/розв’яз-н-ий, розгад-а-ти/ розгад-н-ий, вигой‑і‑ти/вигой-н-ий, стис-ну-ти/стис‑н‑ий.* Якщо твірна дієслівна основа містить у своєму складі суфікс **-ва-**, то від нього відтинаємо кінцевий голосний: *розли-ва- -ти/розли-в-ний, зли-ва- ти/зли-в-н-ий, розсу-ва -ти/ розсу‑в‑ний.* Якщо суфікс **-н-** із якихось причин не може поєднатися з кінцевим приголосним твірної дієслівної основи, добираємо видову пару й утворюємо прикметника від неї: *перевести/перевод-и-ти/перевід-н-ий, перенести/перенос-и-ти/ перенос‑н‑ий*.
>
> Коли ж і надалі ми не можемо утворити прикметника (точніше, виходить щось немилозвучне та кострубате, як-от: *вгамувати — *вгамний, порівняти — *порівнний, знищити — *знищний*), тоді прикметник можна утворити таким чином: а) від твірної дієслівної основи з суфіксом **-ува-** відтяти кінцевий голосний **а**, відновити в усіченому суфіксі первинний голосний **о** та додати суфікса **-н-**: *вгам-ува-ти* ( давніше *вгамовати - вгам-ов-ний*); б) від твірної дієслівної основи відітнути дієслівний суфікс **-а-** або **-и-** і додати прикметниковий **-анн-** чи **-енн-** : *порівн-я-ти, порівн-янн-ий, знищ-и- ти -знищ-енн-ий, узагальн-и-ти -узагальн-енн-ий;* в) перетворити дієприкметника на прикметника, змінивши місце наголосу: *вáрений — варéний, пéчений — печéний* або використати дієприкметника без змін: *комбінований, мішаний* (тобто ад’єктивувати дієприкметника).

Comment: Можливо, упроваджувачі терміна _зліченний_ не хотіли омонімії зі словом _[злічний](//pisni.org.ua/songs/618940.html)_ ([інші варіанти: зличний, злишний,  сличний, слічний](http://swpw.eu/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Forum-Wschodnie-62018.pdf#page=78)) [у значенні «прекрасний, гарний»](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/20306-zlychnyj.html). Окрім того на момент уведення цього терміна в обіг уже давно побутувало слово [незліченний](//sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=59095&page=1884). А на вибір між _перелічний_ і _переліченний_ ніщо не впливало, робили «з чистого аркуша».

Comment: @Sasha Я підозрював, що *злічний* має ще якесь значення, та гадаю, що все ж на вибір між *перелічний* і *переліченний* мала б впливати наявність *зліченний*.

Answer (score 2):

Про наростка **-енн-** можна читнути ві проєктному правопису 1999 року. Він хоч далеко не чинний, але непогано розкриває суть.

> [§ 26](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/26.html). Прикметникові і дієприкметникові суфікси
>
> 2. Прикметникові суфікси **-анн-(ий)**, **-енн-(ий)**, які вживаються для підкреслення найвищої міри ознаки, пишемо з двома **н**: *невблага́нний, нездола́нний, неоціне́нний, несказа́нний, нескінче́нний, страше́нний* (але *жада́ний*, бо в ньому немає такого підкреслення) (див. [§ 23](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/23.html), п. 2). Такі прикметники завжди мають наголос на суфіксі, що відрізняє їх від дієприкметників, утворених від дієслівних коренів за допомогою суфіксів **-ан-(ий)**, **-ен-(ий)**: *ба́жаний, незлі́чений, неоці́нений, неподо́ланий, неска́заний, нескі́нчений*.

> [§ 23](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/23.html). Подвоєння приголосних
>
> 2. Буквосполучення **нн** пишемо:
>
>    а) у наголошеному суфіксі **-енн-(ий)** прикметників, які вказують на більшу, ніж звичайна, чи найбільшу міру якості або можливість й неможливість дії: *височе́нний, здорове́нний, силе́нний, невблага́нний, недоторка́нний, нездійсне́нний, нездола́нний, незліче́нний, незрівня́нний, непримире́нний, несказа́нний, страше́нний, числе́нний, нескінче́нний* та в прикметнику *стара́нний* з відтінком підсилення (див. [§ 26](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/26.html), п. 2);
>
>    б) у прикметниках на **-енн-(ий)**, **-янн-(ий)** старословʼянського походження: *благослове́нний, блаже́нний, мерзе́нний, огне́нний, окая́нний; свяще́нний, спасе́нний*, а також *боже́ственний*. Буквосполучення **нн** зберігається в іменниках та прислівниках, утворених від таких прикметників: *нездола́нність, нездола́нно, числе́нність, числе́нно* тощо.

Приклад має *[злі́чений](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=36591&page=1153)* проти *[зліче́нний](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=208108&page=1153)*. Тлуми з словника в 20 книгах i [Синявський](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky) згідні з цим.

> **Злі́чений**, **а**, **е**. Дієпр. пас. до **злічи́ти**.

> **Зліче́нний**, **а**, **е**, *мат.* Елементи якого можна занумерувати натуральними числами; зчисленний.

Синявський навіть зазначає коли треба додавати **-ен-**, а **-енн-** має подібну поведінку.

> [§ 89](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovozmina_diyeslovo). Дієприкметники
>
> Тільки треба памʼятати, що перед **-ний** буде **е** (**є**) в усіх дієприкметниках тоді, коли вони творяться від дієйменників із приголосним (крім **р**), **й**, **і**, **ї**, або **ну** перед **-ти**: *нести – несений, носити – ношений, вертіти – верчений, напоїти – напоєний, одягнути – одягнений* тощо. В інших випадках голосний перед **-ний** той самий, що і в дієйменнику.

Схоже, тут О. Кочерга, В. Пілецький надають геть не матчастину, а уяву, про шчо вони і самі зазначають, бо наприклад з тих ж *[порівнянний](http://sum.in.ua/s/porivnjannyj), [знищенний](https://slovnyk.me/dict/vts/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), узагальненний*  останє не існує..

Але лишило ся питанє — відки *перелічний*? Насправді тут нічого складного: корїнь справді один, але [пнї](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) ріжні. Як вже знаємо, умовне *переліченний* то від дїйослова *переліч-ити*, а *перелічний* від іменника *перелік* (пор. *бічний* від *бік*).

За тлумом, наприклад [ВТСУМ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)-а, теж добре підходе.

> **Перелічний** Якого можна перелічити.

Можна навести схожу пару з гиншими словами з тлумами від СУМ-11-а: *[розкладний](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) – [розкладений](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)*.

> **Розкладни́й** Який можна розкласти, розсунути, розгинаючи, розпрямляючи в місцях згину, зʼєднання.

> **Розкла́дений** Дієпр. пас. до **розкла́сти**

Тому часто **іменник** + **ний** зі значенєм „який можна“ добре пасує до Анґлійського наростка **able**. А **-енн-**, котрого радять, теж можна умовно, але лише для декотрих слів, бо може мати гиншого значеня і поки немає узуса для загала.

Comment: [знищенний](https://slovnyk.me/dict/vts/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9). Не розумію чому уявне, вони просто пропонують правило.

Comment: @Yola, ем, якшчо вони радять, то такого шче не існує, отже уявне.

Comment: а де вони зазначають про те, що це *геть не матчастина, а уява*?

Answer (score 0):

До **зліченних іменників** відносять живі і неживі предмети, а також поняття і явища, які можна порахувати. Наприклад: два собаки, п'ять книжок, три мрії.

До **незліченних іменників** зазвичай належать ті, що позначають деяку масу або речовину. Наприклад: вода, сіль, м'ясо, багато / не багато сонця, дощу.

**Перелічним** може бути **номер** в армійському або фізкультурному строю, де "на перший-другий, розрахуйсь. Перелічні номери один, два кроки вперед; перелічні номери два, три кроки вбоки".

**Нумеровані** зазвичай бувать **списки** або **рядки** у таблицях.

**Переліченний** - такого в українській мові не існує, але є **порахований**.

Comment: Що таке *перелічні номери один"?

Comment: *Порахований* - це той, що його порахували, а *переліченний*, я думав, що це той який можна перелічити. Тому незрозуміло чому вони згадані разом.

Comment: Вживання «Перелічені» буде калькою. Українською кажуть: відповідно до Приведених або Наведених раніше прикладів.

Comment: Можна порахувати предмети або полічити їх кількість, але не можна перелічити причини чи обставини, їх можна лише назвати.

Comment: @RomanMikhol, зверніть увагу на кількість -н-, вона має велике значення: скі́нчений і скінче́нний, злі́чений і зліче́нний — це зовсім різні речі. (Отже в запитанні мова про (гіпопетично можливе) слово переліче́нний, а не про слово перелі́чений. До речі, слово [перелі́чений](http://sum.in.ua/s/perelichenyj) таки існує.)

Comment: @Sasha саме таку, як за прикладом кальковану мову і мав на увазі. У п'ятдесятих-шістдесятих роках минулого століття українську безжально нищили, викорінювали. За вашим прикладами краще сказати: "усіх названих посад" та "по кутках полічено скільки дворів та по скільки душ".

Comment: @RomanMikhol, добре, розумію і згоден (щодо того, що варто вживати власні форми, а не скальковані, і «перелічений» цілком можливо належить до останніх). Однак, знов-таки, йдеться про «переліче́нний», а не «перелі́чений».

Comment: @Sasha, чи могли б ви пояснити зміст слова «переліче́нний» або навести приклад вживання цього слова у простому реченні?

Comment: Вибачте за затримку з відповіддю. Це, мабуть, краще запитати в автора запитання (@Yola), але я так розумію, що в загальному сенсі: той (ті), який (які) можна перелічити (аналогічно до зліченний, зчисленний тощо). У принципі, мені здається, у математиці це фактично означатиме [одне й те саме](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Зліченна_множина), і я не дуже розумію, навіщо ще одне слово (коли є вже зліченний, зчисленний і перелічний) і тим більше не кажу, що його треба вживати _замість_ перелічний — але й причин категорично відмовляти цьому слову теж не бачу.

Comment: ПерелічеННий - це той, що його можна перелічити, тобто в нього є така пасивна здатність. Тоді як перелічеНий - це той, що його перелічили, тобто над ним виконали дію. Тобто перелічеННий може бути ще не перелічеНим.

Comment: @Yola Зрозуміло. Пропоную спочатку написати наукову статтю з обгрунтуванням необхідності запровадження в українській мові слова "перелічити" на додаток до дієслова "полічити". Тоді вже легше буде і з -переліченним

Comment: Мені здається, що ваш допис не відповідає на запитання. Можливо його можна поліпшити?

Comment: Я думаю, що вас однаково зрозуміють не залежно від того чи буде одна -н-, чи дві і, навіть, не зважаючи на префікс. Сучасні лінгвістичні методи перекладу, наприклад, взагалі представляють слова у вигляді векторів і машинному коду однаково, чи є помилка у слові, відповідно до правил мови, чи ні. Аби передавало суть.